# Docker microservice monorepo CI/CD in Azure Pipelines

Tags: docker, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, monorepo

How to architect Azure Pipelines for CI/CD for a MonoRepo consisting of separate micro-services (.NET Core back-end APIs) each with their own Dockerfile, that all use a common library?  The current folder structure is:

```
Common
 /src
SvcA
 /src
 Dockerfile
SvcB
 /src
 Dockerfile
```

I would like to build a Docker container for each project (and push to a docker registry, and deploy to Kubernetes) on successful Pull Request to to the main branch. It would be ideal if it would only build a micro-service if something changed within that path.

Answer (score 0):

Basic problem here is to store hash (which could be git commit) of previous build relevant to each project within mono-repo. Most basic way is to do a separate commit which would store this information and then do git diff on that. However, this may become pretty messy on a scale or if repository is updated frequently.

Our solution is to use an external tool which we are developing - Reliza Hub - essentially, we record every build metadata in there per project within monorepo. Then on each build we retrieve last known release per project and do git diff command between current commit and last known commit of the project. And if there is diff we rebuild.

Here is a sample of this logic working on our Dockerfile repository under GitHub Actions: https://github.com/relizaio/dockerfile-collection/blob/master/.github/workflows/dockerimage.yml

Particularly, this yaml block does the trick:

```
        dir=maven-postgresql
        dobuild=false
        last_commit=$(docker run --rm relizaio/reliza-cli getlatestrelease -i ${{ secrets.RELIZA_MAVEN_POSTGRESQL_API_ID }} -k ${{ secrets.RELIZA_MAVEN_POSTGRESQL_API_KEY }} --branch $GITHUB_REF | jq -r ".sourceCodeEntryDetails.commit")
        if [ ! -z "$last_commit" ]
        then
          echo -n "--commits $(git log $last_commit..$GITHUB_SHA --date=iso-strict --pretty='%H|||%ad|||%s' -- $dir | base64 -w 0) " > commit_list
          difflines=$(git diff $last_commit..$GITHUB_SHA $dir | wc -l)
          if [ "$difflines" != "0" ]
          then
            dobuild=true
          fi
        else
          dobuild=true
        fi
        if [ "$dobuild" == "true" ]
            # actual build logic goes here
```

Now, for Azure DevOps I don't have full monorepo sample, but sample implementation for single project repo for Azure DevOps in general can be found here: https://github.com/relizaio/reliza-hub-integrations/blob/master/AzureDevOps/azureDevOpsBuildPush.yaml

It is possible then to use similar technique as per GitHub Actions under Azure Devops. Then builds are going to run for each component project only if there is known diff for that particular project.